# guitar wireless micing question

Tags: live-sound, wireless, guitar, microphone-positioning, mounting

How would you mount a wireless mic pack like [this one](http://www.shure.com/americas/products/wireless-systems/uhfr-systems/ur1-wireless-bodypack-transmitter)

to guitar without damaging the guitar or impeding the player?

[EDIT] oh and the strap is not preferable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put a pack on an acoustic before in Theatre, you just provide a new strap and sew an elastic pouch to it. Run the cable down the strap and tape the mic in place / jack plug.

Obviously easier to do when you have a wardrobe department available, but shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: AH the strap is no good, its a prop made of twine (also in theatre) and haas funny way of attaching to the guitar that would make cabling difficult.

Comment: It's a prop of twine, but still being 'played'?

Comment: the strap is a prop made of twine the guitar is normal guitar

Comment: Ah, and have you tried popping the pack ( aerial up ) in the players top rear 'bum' pocket, and running cable to the acoustic? if they need  to remove themselves from it easily, the mic can be held on by velcro, for easy fitting/dismounting. I've also put a pack on the rear of an acoustic. Shit loads of sticky velcro, the pack in a pouch also with velcro.

Comment: velcro eh? alright I'll give it a try thanks man